# Map kubernates Volume attributes in Spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Anyone who has worked on CSI driver Key Vault Secrets, I want to map the below volume attributes in a Spinnaker pipeline.

```
 volumes:
       - name: secrets-store-inline
         csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
           secretProviderClass: "testpoc"
          nodePublishSecretRef:
           name: secrets-store-creds-test
```

Comment: yes, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to have these volume attributes mapped to Spinnaker pipeline without missing any of these attributes. How can we do that.